# TypeError using ZipFile.extractall

Tags: python

I am trying to use zipfile to extract all zip files from a folder into that folder, but am getting a TypeError:

```
TypeError: extractall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

My script looks like

```
import os
from zipfile import *


for file in os.listdir():
  if file.endswith(".zip"):
    ZipFile.extractall(path= "M:\path\...\path", members=file,pwd="password!")
```

Does anyone know why this would be the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the [`ZipFile.extractall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) function wrong.

You can extract one zip file using:

```
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', mode='r')
zf.extractall(pwd='password'.encode('ascii'))

zf.close()
```

To extract all files with the ending `.zip`, you can do:

```
import zipfile
import glob

files = glob.glob('*.zip')
for f in files:
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(f, mode='r')
    zf.extractall(pwd='password'.encode('ascii'))
    zf.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I supply a password? I have tried editing the 7th line but get a TypeError and a SyntaxError respectively for these: 

 'zf.extractall(pwd=password!)'
and 
' zf.extractall(pwd="password!") '

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith(".zip"):
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r')
        z.extractall(path=os.path.dirname(f))
        z.close()
```